# How to start/stop/edit cron job from Node.js?

Tags: node.js, cron

I have did some search for this question, but something useful didn't came out. So, i decided to create a new thread.

**Problem Description**

I am making CLI for installation of our server, so one of the pre-requisite is that cron job should be running. So, to accomplish same, i want to add some cron jobs and restart the service. Is it possible via Node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this module, will this help you?

https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron

Comment: This doesn't fit my requirement as i am not looking for alternative to system cron. I want to kickoff cron service.